# MVC not opening links how it should "controller/action"

Tags: php, model-view-controller, autoload

So i am new to MVC and im trying to understand how this works.

As i understood this is how the autoloder should open

> http://www.example.com/controller/action.

I have this is my indexAction

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->setVars([
        'name' => 'Stefan',
    ]);
}
```

And this in my index.phtml

```
<h1>Hello <?php echo $name ?></h1>
```

But when i call my local-host this is how he tried to open it.

```
Page not found: \Mvc\ControllerInterface\IndexControllerInterface::IndexAction
```

Here is my full autoloader

```
    <?php
// simple autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($className)
{
    if (substr($className, 0, 4) !== 'Mvc\\')
    {
        // not our business
        return;
    }

    $fileName = __DIR__.'/'.str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, substr($className, 4)).'.php';

    if (file_exists($fileName))
    {
        include $fileName;
    }
});

// get the requested url
$url      = (isset($_GET['_url']) ? $_GET['_url'] : '');
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);

// build the controller class
$controllerName      = (isset($urlParts[0]) && $urlParts[0] ? $urlParts[0] : 'index');
$controllerClassName = '\\Mvc\\ControllerInterface\\'.ucfirst($controllerName).'ControllerInterface';

// build the action method
$actionName       = (isset($urlParts[1]) ? $urlParts[1] : 'index');
$actionMethodName = ucfirst($actionName).'Action';


//var_dump($url,$urlParts,$controllerName,$actionMethodName);
//
try {
    if (!class_exists($controllerClassName)) {
        throw new \Mvc\Library\NotFoundException();
    }

    $controller = new $controllerClassName();

    if (!$controller instanceof \Mvc\Controller\ControllerInterface || !method_exists($controller, $actionMethodName)) {
        throw new \Mvc\Library\NotFoundException();
    }

    $view = new \Mvc\Library\View(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'views', $controllerName, $actionName);
    $controller->setView($view);

    $controller->$actionMethodName();
    $view->render();

} catch (\Mvc\Library\NotFoundException $e) {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo 'Page not found: '.$controllerClassName.'::'.$actionMethodName;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo 'Exception: <b>'.$e->getMessage().'</b><br><pre>'.$e->getTraceAsString().'</pre>';
}
```

And here is my folder structure.

[image]

I tried playing around with the folder Structure and with my xxamp httpd conf.
But nothing relly works.

What am i missing here.

Comment: You can see my framework sample. https://github.com/nsleta/ns-framework/tree/master . There is less code there, so you will understand how it works. I am using composer autoload. This is the same as spl_autoload but generated by composer and it's easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I can see wrong.

First you are ending `$controllerClassName` with "ControllerInterface" whereas your class according to your directory structure your index controller is `IndexController`.

Secondly when checking if an object is not an instance of a particular class you need to wrap the negated check in parenthesis e.g. `if (!($controller instanceof \Mvc\Controller\ControllerInterface)){}` see example 3 here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php